# Can I make emulation tag be type mifare 1k

Tags: python, sqlite, nfc, mifare

I have to read emulation tag (PN532) and must to use nfc-mfclassic in libnfc only because I want to get .mfd file from that command  to save anything in block in order to insert to database (sqlite3) in python ,,,
Anybody know about this problem ,help me please!